# how to call and automatically run plumber api from php

Tags: php, r, api, exec, plumber

I am creating Web Application where all my data is retrieved from package. I have constructed an API using plumber and I want to call the API and run automatically when needed from front-end. All time when I wanted to do anything in the front-end I have to switched to R Studio and to the file plumber api and run the file while clicking on RUN API in R Studio. Instead of clicking on RUN API I want to write a code which will of automatically RUN API when its call from front end. this application is going to be live.

for example :- I have used exec ,shell-exec and passthru

```
<?php
       exec ('start_API/callapi.R');
    ?>



<?php
   passthru('start_API/callapi.R');
?>
```

Please Help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you look into into hosting your plumber R process on the same machine as your php process? You can run it as a service. See https://github.com/meztez/plumberDeploy/blob/master/inst/server/plumber.service

Comment: No i haven't done yet this thing. Thank you for your response.